# Is there an opportunity to get the index of an specific array by the the UUID and then add something to it? [Swift UI]

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui

so i am working on a Project in Xcode and I need help. I am kinda new to Swift and I need to get the Index of a Item in a Array by the UUID, so here is some Code:

```
struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id =  UUID()
    var name: String
    var members: Array<Member>
}
```

```
@State var groupIndex: Int = 0

var tgroup: Group


// in the body:

ForEach(Array(groups.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, textItem) in 
    if groups[index].id == tgroup.id {
        Text(String(index)) // and I need this index to be the groupIndex var
        ...
    }
```

but in the Body I am not allowed to change a var, how can I get this index? At the end I want to add something to the same Array.

Thank You!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your code? What var are you trying to change in the body and for what reason?

Comment: what is `groups`... an array of `Group`? Please post a [Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So @TomasJablonskis i am trying to change the groupIndex to the index of the the used group, which is tgroup :)

Comment: @Paullim oh... you cannot do that in the body. Changing a State/Published/ObservedObject/StateObject/etc. re-renders your view hierarchy, so by changing the groupIndex when current view is rendering, you would put the view rendering process into an infinite rendering loop. So the question is why are you trying to save the group index? What is the PURPOSE?

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Thank you for the answer, so I want the user to add items(members) to the group with :groups[].members.append(Member(name: newMem, sex: "m"))   and at the beginning I need a index and that hast to be the one from the group where the user currently is. I. am very new and I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: And the Problem is, I can't do the ForEach anywhere else as the body, but in the Body I can't save the Index

Comment: are you trying to "save" the index now? You can do that using `groupIndex = index`

Comment: @workingdog not inside the Body as I know and outside I can't use "ForEach"

Comment: @Paullim can you post more code? This piece of code does not give enough context.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need/meaning to try to get the `index` in the `ForEach` loop.
To get the index of `tgroup` inside `groups`, just do this:

```
func getGroupIndex() -> Int? {
    return groups.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == tgroup.id})
}
```

and do not put this in the `ForEach` loop, keep using:

```
ForEach(Array(groups.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, textItem) in
    if textItem.id == tgroup.id {
        Text(String(index)) // and I need this index to be the groupIndex var
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: here is the code I used for testing

```
struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id =  UUID()
    var name: String
    var members: Array<String> // <-- for testing
}

struct GroupIndexView: View {
    @State var groups: [Group]
    var tgroup: Group
    
    @State var groupIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(groups.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, textItem) in
            if groupIndex == index {  // <--- here
                Text(String(index)) // and I need this index to be the groupIndex var
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let ndx = getGroupIndex(of: tgroup) {
                groupIndex = ndx
            }
            print("---> groupIndex: \(groupIndex)")
        }
    }
    
    func getGroupIndex(of group: Group) -> Int? {
        return groups.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == group.id})
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var groups: [Group] = [Group(name: "name-1", members: []), Group(name: "name-2", members: [])]

    var body: some View {
        GroupIndexView(groups: groups, tgroup: groups[1])
    }
}
```